# How to learn C++ by writing an editor?

Tags: c++, open-source, scintilla

I would like to participate in some open source projects.

I know a little c++ but I have not yet created a project with it: I want to learn c++ better. In order to participate in some open source project I think I need to familiarize myself with  c++ because open source project's code are rather complex.

So I'm planning to create as a learning exercise a simple editor, like notepad++ but much simpler.

Is there any [scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) like library out there? I searched in google but haven't found anything.

If I'm going in the wrong direction, would anyone tell my about a better way to learn c++? I'm not looking for a "silver bullet" but for a project to learn?

Comment: Please try to write one **clear** question and not several. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to understand what a good stackoverflow question is. And, by the way, welcome to SO. :)

Comment: Don't ask for "the best way to learn C++", because nobody can answer a question like this. It only causes a big discussion, which is not what SO is for. If you are looking for a library with specific characteristics, best simply describe the characteristics you are looking for as precisely as possible.

Comment: @GoogleCredentials Im just asking.. How come that some can answer this question if nobody can answer. Im a beginner not a pro. But thanks anyway..

Comment: @GoogleCredentials This guy want some guidance. Although the question is not good but come to think of it, he is a beginner. A lot of beginners out there are troubled where to start. and if this question wasn't ask right now, surely someone will ask in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is very good. Trying to learn a language by embarking on a project is an excellent idea. Just keep in mind that a project, even a "simple" one like a text editor, can be much larger than you expect at first, and be prepared for making a lot of false starts and having to rewrite a lot of code. After all, that's the point of exercising.

What is not clear to me is why you are not satisfied with scintilla but at the same time are looking for an alternative. I would recommend to start playing with it and getting a first taste of what a "complete" project looks like (for some definition of "complete") and then you will be in a better position to appreciate the strengths and weaknesses of scintilla or of the other various libraries.

On the side of learning C++, since you are asking for suggestion, I can recommend a book: [Accelerated C++ by A. Koening and B. Moo](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/).

Comment: I think its my nature to find the best library out there and study. Cause you know, In the world we live in today there are lots of library out there. So i think even scintilia has a rival. and thanks by the way. I realy wanted to learn.

Comment: Researching is a good idea but since you are starting, pick one library (scintilla could be the one) and start learning. Too many choices can be confusing when starting.

Answer (score 2):

So, start writing a simple editor. It's not that easy, but not terribly hard either, if you have the basics of file handling and GUI covered.

Comment: But you know other library than scintilia?

Comment: No, certainly not in C++. Sorry, I thought you may want to start from scratch, not paste a new GUI on an existing editors guts.

Comment: Well i realy dont know how to start. But i think in order to have a better understanding i should see how the library act. I created a system before but im totally new creating an application.

Comment: What is the largest C++ program you have written so far?

Comment: Nothing at all. I started in vb then move to php and html then move to csharp and android app. Now i want to learn c++.. But i know c++. You can say im in the beginner level in c++

Comment: So, start by writing something a lot more simple than an editor. C++ has a lot more features and pitfalls than VB, C# and Java.

Comment: can you suggest me something simpler than editor?  Like moving to intermediate level?

Comment: If text editor is what your interest is, perhaps writing a very simple, line based editor, using console output only. That will teach you the basics, and still be enough of a useful thing to get you started in the right direction. So, you would have basic editing commands like "l filename" to load a file, "d <linenumber>[-linenumber]" to delete one or more lines, "i [linenumber]" to insert a line (at end if no linenumber given), and an "e linenumber" to alter the contents of a line. This should be possible to do in generic, portable code as well.